# Try manufacturer iwlwifi driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

Since I have been issues with my WiFi, I would like to try a driver I found on the manufacturers site. Whether this will improve anything is questionable, but I'm running out of options..

Anyway, what would be the best way to go about it? I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 (3.5.0.48 kernel) and have downloaded the tgz container with the ucode file I suspect I will be needing. It would be nice to be able to revert to the current version easily if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `/lib/firmware` contains all those drivers, and copying the driver there should suffice. Moreover it turns out I already have the same version.